# For what purpose is _pthread_cond_timedwait function used in v8?

Tags: node.js, performance, chromium, v8

In the profiling logs of chrome (--prof) option with a webpage, a majority of ticks is consumed by _pthread_cond_timedwait function in C++.

[image: log]

What purpose is this used for? Is it used by the profiling thread? or is it waiting for some network request to finish loading?

Also, what are these 'ticks' terminology used in here and V8's profiling tools?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means that the thread was sleeping, waiting for something to do. Maybe it was waiting for a network request, or maybe for something else, such as the next scheduled callback.